# How connect to Microsoft Azure (MSA) Windows Server (WIN) with Remote Desktop (RDP) in Linux

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, remote-desktop

**PROBLEM**

After create new "Virtual Machine (VM)" every time I get

```
$ rdesktop {ip_addr}
ERROR: recv: Connection reset by peer
```

How can I connect?

Comment: You should move the Solution portion to an answer if those steps solved your problem.  After a set amount of time, you will be able to accept your own answer.

Comment: This system allow me do that made answer after one day not earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Disable "Network Level Authentication (NLA)"

1. connect with RDP with NLA - best from another OS "Microsoft Windows (MS WIN)"
2. open "Server Manager"
3. choose "Local Server"
4. click to "Enabled" in "Remote Desktop"
5. uncheck "Allow connections only from computers running Remote Desktop with Network Level Authentication (recommended)"